# want to split the key and filter after __ key in object key

Tags: javascript

```
sample = {
  name__subcatogary: 'help',
  name__Angel: 'sample'
}
```

want to sort or filter the object after __ key in object

i used the sort and filter but i am not able to split it first and

```
this.sample = res.msg.recordset[0];
console.log(">>>>>>>>>",this.sample.split('__')[1].filter())
```

filter the object

```
sample = {
  name__Angel: 'help',
  name__subcatogary: 'sample'
}
```

Comment: Can any one help me please stuck in this

Comment: Objects don't lend themselves to being sorted. You would normally use an array if order is important.

Comment: it is array of object

Comment: There are no arrays in your example. Arrays have `[ ]`.

Comment: this.sample = res.msg.recordset[0];

Comment: we can remove the the this.sample= res.msg.recordset then it will com in array of object

Comment: So you want to sort the array `recordset`? What do you want to sort it by? You need to add a clearer example if you want help. Show what you are starting with, what you want at the end, and explain the logic.

Comment: ok i am having array of object and i want to display the data in sort like a b c so i want to sort the object and display the values in Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(sample)
    .map(key => ({key: key, fixed: key.split('__')[1], value: sample[key]}))
    .filter(item => filterFunction(item.fixed))
    .reduce((p, c) => (p[c.key] = c.value) && p, {})
```

1. Take the keys with `Object.keys`.
2. `map` new array of objects with the origin key, value, and **fixed** key.
3. `filter` the array with your *'filterFunction'*.
4. Create new object with filter keys, using `reduce`.